# Number of lines passing through a fixed point in a quadric surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose that $S \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a smooth quadric surface. Let $p \in S$. Can more than two lines $l \subset S$ pass through $p$? If not, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach to this problem is to use the isomorphism from $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ to the smooth quadric surface $S \subset \mathbb{P}^3$.  In coordinates, the map $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ is given by
$$
(X_0;X_1), (Y_0;Y_1) \mapsto (X_0 Y_0; X_0 Y_1; X_1 Y_0; X_1 Y_1),
$$
with the image being $S = \{ (X;Y;Z;W) : XW = YZ \}$.  One can show that the map is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ to $S$.  And a curve of degree $(d,e)$ in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ maps to a curve of degree $d + e$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  In particular, lines on $S$ correspond to curves in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.  Thus, for a point $(P,Q) \in \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, there are two lines through $(P,Q)$, namely $\{P\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \{Q\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The tangent space $T_p S$ can be thought as a hyperplane $H\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ and any line $l\subset S$ passing through $p$ is contained in this hyperplane.
On the other hand, as $S$ is smooth, it is irreducible, so the intersection $H\cap S$ is of dimension $1$ and has the same degree as $S$, namely $2$.
Each line in $H\cap S$ adds one to this degree so there are at most two lines.
The same argument works for a surface of degree $d$, showing that the number of lines is at most $d$.

Comment: So are there at most $2$ lines, or exactly $2$ lines? Does this depend on the base field? Thank you!

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, there are always 2 lines.  For a general field, it is possible that the two lines are not defined over the base field.  For example if $S = V(X^2 + Y^2 = ZW)$, then the two lines through the point $(0;0;0;1)$ are $X + iY = 0, Z = 0$ and $X - iY = 0, Z = 0$.  Even though $S$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, the lines are only defined over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: thank you! and... just one line defined over the base field is an impossible situation, right?

Comment: Yes, the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ will either interchange the two lines (when neither is defined over $k$) or fix both (when both are defined over $k$).